# Url authentication to fetch redirect or final URL in python

Tags: python

I am using google api to fetch audit logs. The code work fine and generate a URL .
I paste this URL on my browser and it ask for g-mail login authorization.
After authorizing it will redirect me to new URL.

I tried doing this automatically with python code but couldn't able to authenticate before getting final/redirect URL.

I tried following code but no success:

```
import urllib2, base64

request = urllib2.Request("http://api.foursquare.com/v1/user")
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

How is this possible to authenticate and redirect to final URL using python?

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously consider using python's [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library for accessing the API. [Basic authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) is this easy with requests:

```
requests.get('http://api.foursquare.com/v1/user', auth=('username', 'password'))
```

It will automatically follow any redirects. I doubt you need to follow redirects when using basic authentication with the foursquare api, but requests [will do this too](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) if you need it.